# Variance of expectation conditional on marginal distribution

Tags: variance, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

Let $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)$ be a joint distribution with marginal distributions $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.

Let $X$ also be a random variable.

Is it the case that:
$$\mathbf{Var}\left(\mathbf{E}(X|Y)\right)\geq\mathbf{Var}\left(\mathbf{E}(X|Y_1)\right)?$$
If so, how does one prove this?

Comment: Variance of what?  What randomness is left after running the expectation operator over it?

Comment: @wolfies I believe the OP considers the conditional expectation function (i.e. conditioning on the sigma algebra generated by the conditioning variables), which is a random variable, rather than the conditional expected value (conditioning on some realization of the conditioning variables), which is a constant.

Comment: Aren't there missing assumptions here? We know nothing about any connection of X with Y1 and Y2.  How do we know conditionally or unconditionally whether or not X has a finite expectation?

Comment: @MichaelChernick You 're right, but from my experience in questions like these, existence/finiteness of moments is silently assumed

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos For clarity to the rest of us isn't it bast for the OP to include or at least edit to add those assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\mathbb{E}[X|Y_1]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]|Y_1]$$is a projection of $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ the variance of $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ is larger than the variance of its conditional expectation $ \mathbb{E}[X|Y_1]$. (This is a probabilistic version of the Pythagorean theorem.)

Comment: Thanks. I see that this is a duplicate but I like your answer @Xi'an as it accords with the intuition that averaging over one of the "dimensions" will reduce variance.